# s3 failing on preflight even with cors all methods and origins

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, cors

I don't understand... it seems simple, yet it fails on the options call for the put request. "Response for preflight is invalid"

S3 CORS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

The url:

```
http://localhost:9002/api/sign_s3?file_name=wCyQZgrKIS24oR4MV4hdPP-UXDNQ6P9MvOj6DRMPcJU.jpg&file_type=image/jpeg
```

The url to s3 (keys removed):

```
https://jayehtest.s3.amazonaws.com/wCyQZgrKIS24oR4MV4hdPP-UXDNQ6P9MvOj6DRMPcJU.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=xxx&Content-Type=image%2Fjpeg&Expires=1454923884&Signature=xxx&x-amz-acl=public-read
```

The code to generate the put:

```
    Aws.config.update({accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY, secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY});
    var s3 = new Aws.S3();
    var s3_params = {
        Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
        Key: req.query.file_name,
        //Expires: 120,
        //ContentType:  req.query.file_type,
        ContentType: "multipart/form-data",
        ACL: 'public-read-write',
    };
    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3_params, function(err, data){
        console.log('got signed url!');
        if(err)
            res.status(500).json({error: err});
        else
            res.status(200).json({
                signed_request: data,
                url: 'https://'+process.env.S3_BUCKET+'.s3.amazonaws.com/'+req.query.file_name
            });
    });
```

The code to make the put request:

```
    Superagent('get', '/api/sign_s3?file_name='+files[0].name+'&file_type='+files[0].type).end(function(err, response) {
            console.log('signs3 response: ', response);

            Superagent('put', response.body.signed_request)
            //Superagent('put', 'https://jayehtest.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/10172871_10101161917002037_713851410092755221_n.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJOQ7AL7QGIGSXMQQ&Content-Type=image%2Fjpeg&Expires=1454947575&Signature=nBvjbkCLD5XsvFktEjnQOTdRFzM%3D&x-amz-acl=public-read'
            .set('x-amz-acl', 'public-read-write')
            .set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
            .attach('image', files[0])
            .end(cb);
        });
```

Comment: Why did you tag it `node.js`?

Comment: I'm using aws-sdk to generate the put url. I'll add the code, but I also finally figure out how to fix it. took 4 hours of non-stop googling and testing mind you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many stupid layers to S3, but I needed to get a few things perfect:

1. the headers needed to match exactly. Content-Type needed to be character for character the same.
2. x-amz-acl and ACL on node need to both be set to at least public-read
3. You need to generate a bucket policy in s3 that gives permission to your ACCESS_KEY
4. It needs to be a PUT request [but this is something that I resolved quickly]

Notes: I created an IAM user, but then didn't use it. The IAM user didn't even work. It works fine with the public keys.